# Crystal Report: How to make one field data to be two column in Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

sorry i just learn using the CRYSTAL REPORT and I got a problem, I hope no one wants to help find a solution for me.

I have 2 data field, and I want to add one field with the selection of another data field
this field

```
+------------+-------------+
|data_1      |data_2       |
|m           |100          |
|k           |200          |
|m           |230          |
+------------+-------------+
```

i wants reports

```
+------------+-------------+
|m           |k            |
|100         |             |
|            |200          |
|230         |             |
+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have your fields in detail section. To solve your problem make 2 detail sections (section a and section b).

In `section a` put your `data_2` field under your `data_1` label, in `section b` put your `data_2` field under your `data_2` label. Only thing you need to make it work is to write proper formula for suppress in section expert.

For your example

**section a suppress formula** like `if data_1 = m then false else true`

**section b suppress formula** like `if data_1 = m then true else false`

I didn't tested this on some example but i think it should work or at least help you to find proper solution.

Comment: You can use cross tab

Comment: Sure, provide solution then using cross tab :)